# Servlet unavailable in AppEngine with Android Client

Tags: android, apache, google-app-engine

I am getting the following info log in GAE's console:
"POST /xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 133 - "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4),gzip(gfe)"

I can not understand if the servlet is not available, why is "200" being returned. I checked web.xml file for servlet mapping and they seem fine. What else could be causing it. Is it even an error on GAE or is it due to client error.

Answer (score 6):

The string "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" is the client's user agent string. It's not an error - it's the identification the client sent to the server. In this case, 'UNAVAILABLE' is probably in place of the version number of the library.