# Update Existing Data in MySQL Database Using Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have this android project that gets information from the database using JSON. Now, my problem is how can I update an existing data from the database (let's say I want to update the "status" column which has a value of "0" and I want to make it "1"). Is that possible? Here is my code:

> newsfeed_liip_pallet_purchase_order_update.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //initial query
    $query = "UPDATE pims_liip_pallet_purchase_order ( status ) VALUES ( :status ) ";

    //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':status' => $_POST['status'],

    );

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't update post!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Successfully Updated!";
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
?>

    <?php
}

?>
```

> PalletPurchaseOrder_Clicked.java

```
package com.pallet.pts;


public class PalletPurchaseOrder_Clicked extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

     // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private Button  bApprove, bDisapprove;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // Newsfeed JSONArray
    JSONArray mNewsfeed = null;

    // Newsfeed id
    String newsfeed_id = null;


    // URL for data parsing
    private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://192.168.0.101/PMR_Drupal/sites/all/modules/eclipse/newsfeed_liip_pallet_purchase_order_update.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pallet_purchase_order_clicked);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

         cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(PalletPurchaseOrder_Clicked.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

            // Approve and Disapprove Buttons
                    bApprove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnApprove);
            bApprove.setOnClickListener(this);

            bDisapprove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnApprove);
            bDisapprove.setOnClickListener(this);

            // Actionbar 
            ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); //need  import android.app.ActionBar;
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0089fd"));    
                      ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

            // Get intent from the other page
            Intent in = getIntent();
            po_number = in.getStringExtra("po_number");
            date_created = in.getStringExtra("date_created");
            trans_name = in.getStringExtra("trans_name");
            supplier = in.getStringExtra("supplier");
            section_from = in.getStringExtra("section_from");
            term_name = in.getStringExtra("term_name");
            total_amount = in.getStringExtra("total_amount");
            delivery_date = in.getStringExtra("delivery_date");
            date_requested = in.getStringExtra("date_requested");
            requested_by = in.getStringExtra("requested_by");
            prepared_by = in.getStringExtra("prepared_by");
            product_code = in.getStringExtra("product_code");
            product_description = in.getStringExtra("product_description");
            date_prepared = in.getStringExtra("date_prepared");
            quantity = in.getStringExtra("quantity");
            unit_price = in.getStringExtra("unit_price");
            total_amount_paid = in.getStringExtra("total_amount_paid");
            qty_delivered = in.getStringExtra("qty_delivered");
            notes = in.getStringExtra("notes");

            status = in.getStringExtra("status");
            status_id = in.getStringExtra("status_id");

            // calling background thread
            new LoadClicked().execute();
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new LoadClicked().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

     /**
     * Background Async Task to get single song information
     * */
    class LoadClicked extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PalletPurchaseOrder_Clicked.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating Content...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting song json and parsing
         * */
         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // post id as GET parameters
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("po_number", po_number));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);


            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
                if(jObj != null){

                     date_created = jObj.getString(TAG_DATE_CREATED);
                     po_number = jObj.getString(TAG_PO);
                     trans_name = jObj.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                     supplier = jObj.getString(TAG_SUPPLIER);
                     section_from = jObj.getString(TAG_SECTION);
                     term_name = jObj.getString(TAG_TERM);
                     total_amount = jObj.getString(TAG_TOTAL_AMOUNT);
                     delivery_date = jObj.getString(TAG_DELIVERY_DATE);
                     date_requested = jObj.getString(TAG_DATE_REQUESTED);
                     requested_by = jObj.getString(TAG_REQUESTED_BY);
                     prepared_by = jObj.getString(TAG_PREPARED_BY);
                     product_code = jObj.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_CODE);
                     product_description = jObj.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION);
                     quantity = jObj.getString(TAG_QUANTITY);
                     unit_price = jObj.getString(TAG_UNIT_PRICE);
                     total_amount_paid = jObj.getString(TAG_TOTAL_AMOUNT_PAID);
                     qty_delivered = jObj.getString(TAG_QTY_DELIVERED);
                     notes = jObj.getString(TAG_NOTES);  

                     status = jObj.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                     status_id = jObj.getString(TAG_STATUS_ID); 

                }          

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting song information
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    TextView txt_ref_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPTRef);
                    TextView txt_po_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPONumber);
                    TextView txt_trans_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                    TextView txt_date_created = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateCreated);

                    TextView txt_supplier = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSupplier);
                    TextView txt_section = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShipTo);
                    TextView txt_term_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTerm);
                    TextView txt_total_amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmount);
                    TextView txt_delivery_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryDate);
                    TextView txt_date_requested = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateRequested);
                    TextView txt_requested_by = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRequestedBy);
                    TextView txt_prepared_by = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPreparedBy);

                    TextView txt_product_code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProductCode);
                    TextView txt_product_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProductDescription);
                    TextView txt_quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
                    TextView txt_unit_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUnitPrice);
                    TextView txt_total_amount_paid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmountPaid);

                    TextView txt_qty_delivered = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQtyDelivered);
                    TextView txt_notes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNotes);

                    TextView txt_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
                    TextView txt_status_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatusID);

                     //displaying data in view

                    txt_ref_number.setText(ref_number);
                    txt_po_number.setText(po_number);
                    txt_trans_name.setText(trans_name);
                    txt_date_created.setText(date_created);
                    txt_supplier.setText(supplier);
                    txt_section.setText(section_from);
                    txt_term_name.setText(term_name);
                    txt_total_amount.setText(total_amount);
                    txt_delivery_date.setText(delivery_date);
                    txt_date_requested.setText(date_requested);
                    txt_requested_by.setText(requested_by);
                    txt_prepared_by.setText(prepared_by);
                    txt_product_code.setText(product_code);
                    txt_product_description.setText(product_description);
                    txt_quantity.setText(quantity);
                    txt_unit_price.setText(unit_price);
                    txt_total_amount_paid.setText(total_amount_paid);
                    txt_qty_delivered.setText(qty_delivered);
                    txt_notes.setText(notes);

                    txt_status.setText(status);
                    txt_status_id.setText(status_id);

                    // Condition for Status
                    if (status.equals("For Approval")){
                        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnApprove);
                        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnDisApprove);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnApprove);
                        b1.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnDisApprove);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    // Change Activity Title with preferred title
                    setTitle(po_number);
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

How can i update the status? I hope you can help me :D Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can send an HTTP request to a webpage (GET or POST, POST for sensitive data). The server would then parse the data as if it came from a html <form>.

According to this (fairly dated) [blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203356/php-http-post-on-android-device-using-httpurlconnection), the preferred method is [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for android 2.3 and beyond. For older systems, look into the [org.apache.http](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) package or even [android.net.http](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/package-summary.html).

There is also a similar question on SO which uses HttpUrlConnection ([PHP HTTP POST on Android device using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203356/php-http-post-on-android-device-using-httpurlconnection)).